# Controlling visibility of multiple sibling identical components from the same parent while keeping isolated scope

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Using Vue and [Vuetify Data Tables](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables) I built a table in which each row presents an item of an array of objects. 
Each row had a button which triggered a dialog which presented a form in which you could edit each row's data.

Here's the problem with instructions: https://codepen.io/gkatsanos-the-bold/pen/VwZzKeq

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    gateways: [],
    dialog: false,
    form: {
      title: ""
    }
  }),
  mounted() {
    this.getGateways().then(data => {
      this.gateways = data;
    });
  },
  methods: {
    async getGateways() {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
      );
      const data = response.json();
      return data;
    },
    openDialog(item) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.dialog = true;
        this.form.title = this.item.title
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        <v-data-table :items="gateways">
          <template #item="{ item }">
      <tr>
        <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.title }}</td>
        <td>
          <v-menu>
            <template #activator="{ on }">
                <v-btn small class="meter-point-options-menu action-column-item" v-on="on">
                    open menu
                </v-btn>
              </template>
          <v-list>
            <v-list-item>
              <v-btn color="red lighten-2" dark @click="openDialog()">
                Click Me
              </v-btn>
              <v-dialog v-model="dialog" width="500">
                <v-card>
                  <v-card-title>
                    ID: {{ item.id }}
                  </v-card-title>
                  <v-card-title>
                    TEXT: {{ item.title }}
                  </v-card-title>
                  <v-card-text>
                    <br> Issues:
                    <ol>
                      <li>Every time you close and open a Dialog / Popup, all of the previous ones open together because they're still in the DOM.</li>
                      <li>Notice that after navigating the pages, some of the ID and texts shown in the modal dialogs are different from the item opened!</li>

                      <v-form ref=form>
                      </v-form>
                  </v-card-text>
                  <v-card-actions>
                    <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
                    <v-btn color="primary" text @click="dialog = false">
                      close this
                    </v-btn>
                  </v-card-actions>
                </v-card>
              </v-dialog>
            </v-list-item>
          </v-list>
          </v-menu>
          </td>
          </tr>
          </template>
        </v-data-table>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

As you see opening one dialog opens all the previous ones. 
How should I tackle the issue of controlling the visibility of the v-dialogs in a unique fashion? I am thinking of moving them outside of the loop and having only one v-dialog and not one for every row of the table.

Comment: your idea is correct - use one dialog and update references on open

Comment: The problem with this idea ( https://codepen.io/gkatsanos-the-bold/pen/VwZzLpa) is passing the loop items to the component as there are now siblings. It gets ugly.

Comment: not sure what you mean - v-dialog is direct child of v-app independend of were you put it in template - so reusing is just reducing the nodescount

Comment: I mean I need to pass information / variables from the parent component to the v-dialog component, information that is inside the array of objects being lopped. Each item of the array needs to have its own dialog. How do you do this with one instance of the dialog? How do you pass variables in a sibling?

Comment: There is a possibility to add the dialog as a plugin like vuex - then you would do something like `vm.$dialogs.dialogName(data, options)` and `vm.$dialogs.close()`. would this be suitable?

Comment: so kind of accessing it globally? Would I be able to do the same but using $refs instead? I looked for a $refs solution but couldn't find one. If you can post an answer I'd be happy to have a look!!